# How to add additional property with VS2013 regex replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Need to replace:

```
 yield return new Question {QuestionID = 274, QuestionDescription = "WIF15 Notes to solicitor", QuestionCategoryId = 6, QuestionTypeID = 2};
```

to

```
 yield return new Question {QuestionID = 274, QuestionDescription = "WIF15 Notes to solicitor", QuestionText = "WIF15 Notes to solicitor", QuestionCategoryId = 6, QuestionTypeID = 2};
```

So far tried

Find What:

```
 QuestionDescription = \"{.*}\",
```

Replace With:

```
QuestionDescription = "(\1)",  QuestionText = "(\1)",
```

Says couldn't find QuestionDescription = \"{.*}\",

Comment: Your regex fails because of `{.*}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Already solved it myself, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
QuestionDescription = "([^"]*)",
```

Replacement string:

```
QuestionDescription = "$1",  QuestionText = "$1",
```

Answer (score 0):

Done it myself

Find What:

```
QuestionDescription = "(.*)",
```

Replace with:

```
QuestionDescription = "$1",  QuestionText = "$1",
```

Comment: it's better if your regex is `QuestionDescription = "([^"]*)",` . Your regex won't work if the input is `yield return new Question {QuestionID = 274, QuestionDescription = "WIF15 Notes to solicitor", QuestionCategoryId = 6, QuestionTypeID = "2"};`